# Can I store arbitrary attributes on the application's AppConfig class?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

The recommended way to [enable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) a Django application seems to be using 
an application configuration class. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) also states that "you can define any attributes documented in the [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig) API reference" on that class.

I wonder if I can define **custom** application-specific attributes on the configuration class, which I could later access via the [application registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#application-registry). Are there any drawbacks with this approach?